# Is there virtualenv for Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I am totally new to Node.js. Can anyone tell me if there is anything similar to Python's `virtualenv`? I need to run apps on different versions of Node.js on the same machine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### nvm by Tim Caswell

Check out [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) by Tim Caswell, it's a version manager for Node.js. It allows you to install multiple version of Node.js in parallel, and also manages version-independent variants of the global module cache for you. With nvm it basically comes down to:

```
$ nvm install 0.10.24
$ nvm use 0.10.24
```

And then you have Node.js 0.10.24 up and running, including the appropriate version of npm.

Installation of nvm is as easy as running a simple shell command:

```
$ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.2/install.sh | bash
```

Another option may be [n](https://github.com/visionmedia/n) by TJ Holowaychuk or [nave](https://github.com/isaacs/nave) by Isaac Z. Schlueter, although I don't have any experience with either of them.

### n by TJ Holowaychuk

Basically, they work quite similar to nvm. Installing n is as easy as running a shell script, too:

```
$ make install
```

Afterwards you are able to type:

```
$ n 0.10.24
$ n
```

Then you can select which installed version you'd like to use. From what I've **heard** n works better than nvm if you are on Windows.

### nave by Isaac Z. Schlueter

nave is a shell script, again, and its usage is similar to that of nvm:

```
$ nave install 0.10.24
$ nave use 0.10.24
```

And that's it :-)!

Answer (score 2):

I remember that in Python - it comes down to using `pythonbrew` for switching between multiple versions of Python installed on the system (for example 2.7 and 3.0). For this - Node.js analogy would be in using `nvm install` as described by Golo.

When it comes to per project package management - in Python you would use `virtualenv` or `virtualenvwrapper` (even better) to organize modules and specific versions for your project. In Node.js this is assumed (that every project has own dependencies) - and you specify this in `package.json` file.

When you execute `npm install` all your packages are downloaded and installed in **root_dir/.node_modules/** directory (which is local to project, assuming that **root_dir** is root of your Node project).

However, you can still install packages globally for node by using this command:

```
npm install -g "package_name"
```

General rule would be this:

1. If you’re installing something that you want to use in your program, using **`require('whatever')`**, then install it locally, at the root of your project.
2. If you’re installing something that you want to use in your shell, on the command line or something, install it globally, so that its binaries end up in your `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

While nvm etc. are great tools (I use nvm personally), they don't really provide project-specific virtual environments. What if you need two projects to each have access node v0.11.14 but also different versions of global npm packages? You're out of luck with nvm unless you have them wrapped in a true virtual environment. Luckily, there's [nodeenv](http://ekalinin.github.io/nodeenv/), which even integrates into virtualenv projects. Plus, with something like virtualenvwrapper, you can link the environment to a project directory for easy access.

If using virtualenvwrapper:

```
mkvirtualenv -a project_path -i nodeenv --python=`which python2` ENVNAME
deactivate
workon ENVNAME
nodeenv -p [--prebuilt] [--node=NODE_VER] [--npm=NPM_VER]
deactivate
workon ENVNAME
```

The `--python` flag is only necessary if you're on an OS (e.g Arch Linux) that uses python 3 by default, since npm requires python 2. The `deactivate`/`workon` is just good practice to ensure that the changes you make to the environment are fully loaded, which doesn't always happen without doing that.